# jquery carousel move one img at a time

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to build a image carousel and have found a script that works great except for when you hit the scroll buttons it moves a number of images out of the frame at once. I would prefer for it to scroll only one image at a time.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4W4qX/)

And here is the script

```
$.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {

function repeat(str, num) {
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( str );
}

return this.each(function () {
    var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
        $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
        $items = $slider.find('> li'),
        $single = $items.filter(':first'),

        singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(), 
        visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth), // note: doesn't include padding or border
        currentPage = 1,
        pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);            


    // 1. Pad so that 'visible' number will always be seen, otherwise create empty items
    if (($items.length % visible) != 0) {
        $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length % visible)));
        $items = $slider.find('> li');
    }

    // 2. Top and tail the list with 'visible' number of items, top has the last section, and tail has the first
    $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(- visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
    $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
    $items = $slider.find('> li'); // reselect

    // 3. Set the left position to the first 'real' item
    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

    // 4. paging function
    function gotoPage(page) {
        var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
            n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
            left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

        $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
            scrollLeft : '+=' + left
        }, 500, function () {
            if (page == 0) {
                $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                page = pages;
            } else if (page > pages) {
                $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                // reset back to start position
                page = 1;
            } 

            currentPage = page;
        });                

        return false;
    }

    $wrapper.after('<a class="arrow back">&lt;</a><a class="arrow forward">&gt;</a>');

    // 5. Bind to the forward and back buttons
    $('a.back', this).click(function () {
        return gotoPage(currentPage - 1);                
    });

    $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
        return gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
    });

    // create a public interface to move to a specific page
    $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
        gotoPage(page);
    });
});  
 };

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `visible` variable to be 1 then it should work as you would like:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4W4qX/1/)

Or you can use this code - I have added an extra variable of `scrollAmount` in, this gives a better transition at the end of the pages (when it adds extra items in)

[Example with scrollAmount variable](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4W4qX/6/)

Comment: Just another question how would I get the carousel to continually scroll when you click and hold on the nav arrows?

Comment: not too sure about that one - you're probably best asking another question - there'll be some sort of mouse event that you can use

Answer (score 0):

Change before 1st point to this code:

```
return this.each(function () {
    var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
        $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul'),
        $items = $slider.find('> li'),
        $single = $items.filter(':first'),

        singleWidth = $single.outerWidth()/3, 
        visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth)/3, // note: doesn't include padding or border
        currentPage = 1,
        pages = Math.ceil($items.length*3 / visible);            


    // 1. Pad so that 'visible' number will always be seen, otherwise create empty items
```